# React sending local variable to another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, components, local-variables

I am new to React Framework. I am having trouble exporting a usestate value queryCity to another js file.

I have a code React index.js code like below:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

    const Home = () => {
    const [queryCity, setQueryCity] = useState("New York");

     
      return(
      <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            className="search-city"
            placeholder="New York "
            value={queryCity}
            onChange={(e) => setQueryCity(e.target.value)}
          />
 </div>
      );
    };
    
export default Home ;
```

Another file called 'Search.js' needs  the  queryCity from Home module.
I have tried createContext. But the Search.js is not the child component of Home

Comment: `globalCity` is a local constant to the `Home` component and is ONLY available to the the `Home` component. If you want to have access to it, then it should be in a context or some other global state. You can make it a global variable if you wish, but i wouldn't recommend it. Global state is how I'd handle this.

Comment: Thank you, let me try a separate function outside Home

Comment: With React, data can be passed to child components using *props*. If `globalCity` is supposed to be a global constant, declare it in a separate file and import it where necessary.

Comment: I have revised my code.  The variable I have to export is a value of useState which is updated from a user input. I have considered CreateContext. But Search.js is not a child component of Home

Answer (score 1):

Because `globalCity` is scoped to the `Home` component, you will not have access to it in a parent scope.

If you want to access `globalCity` in another file, move it out of the `Home` component and into the parent scope and also export it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const globalCity = "New York";

const Home = () => {
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.  let me try a separate function outside Home

Comment: I have revised my code. The variable I have to export is a value of useState which is updated from a user input. I have considered CreateContext. But Search.js is not a child component of Home. Do I need to use redux?

Comment: No, you do not need to use Redux or context. You just need to lift the state up to a component further up the tree where it can be passed down to where it is needed as a prop. If you are updating the value of that variable, you will also need to pass an updater function as a prop along with it.